# How do you check if a mouse press is on a line in Java

Tags: java, math, geometry, line

I am creating a java application and wanting to make it so that a user can click on a line in order to make an event occur. The line is simply defined by its 2 endpoints, both of which have a x and a y coordinate.

Any ideas on how I can I can check if a position collected from the mouse press event (with a x and y coordinate) can be checked to see if it is on this line?

I want to make it so that the hit detection for the line is a little bit forgiving for the user so that as long as the mouse press is quite close to the line, it will be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea is, you should calculate the distance between the clicked point and your line. If the distance is less than say 2 pixels, consider the click to be close enough.

You can [do the math yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) if you're so inclined. In the Java standard library, the [java.awt.geom.Line2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptSegDist(double,double,double,double,double,double)) class has methods to check the distance between a point and a line or a line segment.

```
double distance = Line2D.ptSegDist​(lineStartX, lineStartY, 
                                   lineEndX, lineEndY,
                                   clickX, clickY);

if (distance < 2) {
    // success!
}
```

Comment: Curious how this behaves if the projection of the point does not belong to the segment. Does it then return the minimum distance between each of the extremities of the segment?

Comment: Yes - ptSegDist returns the *"distance between the specified point and the closest point between the specified end points"*. There is also a line distance method that gives you the distance to the infinitely long line connecting the two points.

Comment: Okay, then that's the right behaviour for this use case, and doesn't require much code from the OP